# Why the button "Go To App" can't add my app?

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbml

Why the button "Go To App" can't authenticate users to add an application?

In my app I've link (on button "Go To App") like this: http://apps.facebook.com/some/

But i need link like this: http://facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=someId&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/some/&response_type=token&fbconnect=1

Answer (score 0):

You can't change how Facebook work!

What you can do is calling the

```
http://facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=someId&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/some/&response_type=token&fbconnect=1
```

From your canvas page `http://apps.facebook.com/some/` if the user is not already *connected* like **ALL** other applications do!